# select2 Placeholder with icon in select multiple

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-select2

I have this code for a placeholder with icon (font Awesome) that work fine:

```
var placeholder = "<span class='fas-icon'>&#xf45f</span> Select...";
    $("#mysel").select2({
        theme: 'bootstrap4',
        dataAdapter: CustomData,
        placeholder: placeholder,
        width: null,
        escapeMarkup: function(m) { 
           return m; 
        }
    });
```

but when add attribute "multiple" at , i see placeholder icon (&#xf45f) only as a text field.

How can I solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: can you show us your code in jsfiddle so that we could be more clear what issue you are facing because you have not added any js or CSS links or plugins you are using for above?

Comment: @AmanjotKaur While it's a good idea to have the OP share the code in a working snippet, it's better to recommend the snippet tool `<>` that StackOverflow provides. That way we can keep it all in 1 site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where you are adding attribute 'multiple', if you provide any working snippet of your code it would be really helpful. Anyway hope so below link will help you.
It's working example of select2 with multiple option

```
HTML:
<select multiple id="e1" style="width:300px">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
        <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
        <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" >Select All

<input type="button" id="button" value="check Selected">

Js:
$("#e1").select2();
```

Here is the working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/pgurav/ywt4hn80/

Comment: this doesn't answer his question, which is icons not beign escaped by the property `escapeMarkup` when the `select` filed is `multiple`